# Is there a way to get HTML 5 video to work on mobile safari | WP CMS with Slider Revolution

Tags: wordpress, html5-video

I have a website that is using the slider revolution plugin to run an HTML5 video in the background of the hero (no sound) and it works fine on desktop. I'm trying to make it work on mobile as well, and I know there was a previously referenced code here that makes this work, however I'm not sure of how to implement this using the plugin.

Nothing yet, I tried looking up previous threads with this topic but none were geared towards WP

Comment: is the video not showing at all, or it is a matter of `autoplay` not working? If you see a black background, for instance, the video might be correctly loaded but it is just not played automatically.

Comment: Hi there, if it's playing on desktop, it should work on mobile. However, on mobile IOS, the video will only be played when it's fully loaded.